# What process is running before I even get a prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, centos, prompt, signals

When I log in to a specific server I see the following:

[image: before ctrl+c]

Note that I get get `Last login: ...` information but no prompt. I hit `Ctrl+C` and only *then* do I get my prompt, thus proving that my username and password are correct, as per the below screen shot.

[image: after ctrl+c]

I've been having this problem since this morning on a web server we have in the office. It's no coincidence that the disks in the machine have been replaced today but all that's happened is the old disk has been cloned and all the other users of the system aren't having this problem.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: If you can CTRL-C out of it, you're definitely running into some login script that is hanging. I would check /etc/profile.d /etc/profile and any .bash_* files in your home directory.

Comment: And if the files Joel's has indicated do not exist, then please be more specific about *which* shell you are running on that server: `fgrep username /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 7`

Comment: I ain't executing that, safe or not. `bash` is my shell.

Comment: the command anthon gave you just returns your username's shell, without doing any harm to your system. you can do it as a normal user, if you are scared.

Comment: you can use `getent passwd username` instead of the fgrep command

Comment: What OS is the server running?  On a Linux system you should be able to log into a second sessions and run something like `ps axf | grep pts` to see what's running.

Comment: @fromnaboo I just did `cat /etc/passwd`, and found myself

Comment: @depquid We're running CentOS

Comment: Although the specific problem isn't reproduced, it seems to me that the basic question and answers given could easily be useful to a future visitor. The answers give an overview of what's probably going on, and basic diagnostic steps which will apply to anyone regardless of the actual mystery, so I've rolled back the edit declaring the problem non-reproducable. Someone else probably _will_ have a similar problem, and the answers here may help.

Comment: @mattdm fair enough, I agree completely about the answers remaining useful but thought I'd update everyone on the matter. Maybe a comment down here would have been more appropriate, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is taking a long time in one of your shell initialization files. Add `set -x` at the top of `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_login`) if your login shell is bash, or `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zlogin` and `~/.zshrc` if it's zsh. This way the shell will print each command before it executes it. Run `set +x` afterwards to turn the tracing off.

The command may be one that's invoked from the system-wide initialization script `/etc/profile`. If you can't change that file but need to see what it does, run a login shell with tracing on, e.g. `bash --login -x`.

Another approach is to log in a second time and watch what's going on with `ps` and other tools. On Linux `ps x` shows all of your processes (a plain `ps` only shows running on the current terminal which does no good here); `ps -t pts/42` restricts to processes running on the terminal `/dev/pts/42` (you'll probably need to run `ps x` first to determine the terminal of the second session).

Comment: I'd recommend try the `ps` approach first, before combing through shell initialization files and having to guess which process might be hanging.

Comment: `ps x` to the rescue! I had an alias in `~/.bashrc` that was failing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead killing process that is hanging your shell, try to stop it with Crtl+Z and then use `jobs` command to see what it was.

Comment: Gave that a go but `Ctrl+Z` has no discernible effect

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a command running in either your $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.profile that is either not being backgrounded correctly or is waiting for input from the user. I'd take a look at those 2 files to start.

If nothing turns up there, then I'd take a look at the system equivalents of those files, /etc/bashrc, /etc/profile, and the files in the directory /etc/profile.d/*. Perhaps someone, a sysadmin, added something to those system level files that's now attempting to run when you login.

Comment: Do you know how the process of cloning and replacing the hard disk would have anything to do with that?

Comment: No. I would need to see your .bashrc and .profile files to get a better sense of what's going on. Either the files I've mentioned or the ones from @Gilles answer are the way to go in terms of debugging the issue further.